# In SQL how to change null values in a view

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have two columns one called BankNo and the other called BranchNo. im running a view that selects the bank numbers along with there branches. One bank doesn't have a branch number so I would like that value to not come up as "null" but to come up as "No Branch". The BranchNo column is a numeric field. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Select BankNo, ISNULL(Cast(BranchNo as nvarchar(10),'No Branch') from BankTable
```

Comment: `The BranchNo column is a numeric field`, says OP. What do you think will happen if you try to run this on a numeric column?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. We need to Cast first then?

Comment: Thanks allot guys. Used this one as it had the bankNo as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Coalesce(Cast(BranchNo as varchar(11)), 'No Branch') As BranchNo
...
```

**`Coalesce()`** function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: `Coalesce()` > `IsNull()` ;-)